# Gravity Form - Custom CSS - Text Colour

Tags: html, css, forms, gravity

Hello Im having some issues changing the text colour of a gravity form placed on the image. The current code is;

```
/*=================place this in the css stylesheet========*/
.row .column {
    box-sizing: border-box;}
.row{
background-image: url(image);
background-size: cover;
  }

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 600px; 

}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both; 
}
```

I can't seem to find where to change the font colour. Am I going about it the wrong way, does it need placing in the WYSIWYG editor?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about Gravity itself but your css does not assign any color to the element, you could try something like:

```
.row {
  background-image: url(image);
  background-size: cover;
  color: red;
}
```

Have a read around [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp)